# Error while running Android Studio on Fedora 23

Tags: java, android, sdk

I see this after running Android Studio as Google wanted me to run it.
[maciej@localhost bin] $ ./studio.sh
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0

JDK Required: 'tools.jar' seems to be not in Studio classpath.
Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.

Comment: Where is your JAVA_HOME pointing to? Try running this from terminal to update your JDK: sudo dnf install install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel

Comment: Thank you good man! It worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment above worked. Adding as answer to help future posters. You need to add the proper JDK and make sure it is specified as home. To do this simply issue this command:

**sudo dnf install install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel**